# How to pre-select and update checkboxes in Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I want to implement a checklist in Angular. Some boxes have to be pre-checked based on an array in the ts file and the array has to be updated when a checkbox is checked. I am doing it like:

```
<div class='form-group que-box' *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options">
  <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox 1" [value]="option.text" name="checkBox" [(ngModel)]="optionsSelectedArray"/>
  <label for='{{option.optionId}}'><span class="que">{{option.text}}</span></label>
</div>
```

`optionsSelectedArray` contains the option IDs retrieved from server.

But it doesn't work. All the checkboxes come checked when the the division is rendered.

**EDIT**

I have changed my code as follows :

```
<div class='form-group que-box' *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{option.optionId}}" name="checkBox" [(ngModel)]="option.userResponse" (ngModelChange)= "setResponseChanged()">
  <label for='{{option.optionId}}'><span class="que">{{option.text}}</span></label>
</div>
```

Here `option.userResponse` in boolean. Now on selecting the checkboxes the currentQuestion object is correctly changing but when the checklist loads for the first time, the checkboxes are not checked correctly.All the checkboxes come checked if the `option.userResponse` is true for the last item ,none come checked otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this might do what you want

```
<div class='form-group que-box' *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options; let i=index">
  <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox 1" name="checkBox" [(ngModel)]="optionsSelectedArray[i]"/>
  <label for='{{option.optionId}}'><span class="que">{{option.text}}</span></label>
</div>
```

(I added `; let i=index` and `[i]`)

Comment: I populated optionsSelectedArray  by boolean values depending on what checkboxes have to be checked.Now the ngModel seems to update just fine when the check boxes are clicked but the checkboxes do not get pre-checked bases on the ngModel values when the checklist first loads. All the checkboxes are rendered checked if last index in the array is true, else none come checked.

Comment: I missed the `[value]="option.text"`, that won't work together with `[(ngModel)]="..."` You need to initialize the `optionsSelectedArray` with the values you want the checkboxes to have initially.

Comment: Your Plnkr helped a lot. Thanks for your patience and response. However the irratic behavior of the check boxes seems to have been removed by choosing unique names for the checkboxes.

Comment: I see. Another thing I missed in your code. Yes, they need to have unique names. You can use `i` to make the unique (I guess this is what you did).