# How to make checkboxes pre selected in angular 11 based on json object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 array of object, one compareJson and other checkboxesDataList ,so on select of checkbox I am comparing the id of both json and getting the filtered value of checkboxesDataList in console.log(matches); I am getting the correct value here. Now I want to pre compare both the json based on id on page load and make pre selected the checkbox. For example C001 and C003 are common in both json so only those data from checkboxesDataList will be pre selected. Here is the code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fst6jp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<ul class="checkbox-items">
  <li *ngFor="let item of checkboxesDataList">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked" (change)="changeSelection()">{{item.label}}
  </li>

</ul>
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of  compareJson">Item listed - {{item.details}}</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  selectedItemsList: any[] = [];
  checkedIDs: any[] = [];
  compareJson = [
    {
      id: 'C001',
      details: 'Photography details'
    },
    {
      id: 'C001',
      details: 'Writing details'
    },
    {
      id: 'C003',
      details: 'Painting Details'
    }
  ];
  checkboxesDataList = [
    {
      id: 'C001',
      label: 'Photography'
    },
    {
      id: 'C002',
      label: 'Writing'
    },
    {
      id: 'C003',
      label: 'Painting'
    }
  ];
  ngOnInit() {}
  changeSelection() {
    this.checkedIDs = [];
    this.selectedItemsList = this.checkboxesDataList.filter((value, index) => {
      return value.isChecked;
    });
    console.log(this.selectedItemsList);
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.selectedItemsList.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.selectedItemsList[i].id);
      this.checkedIDs.push(this.selectedItemsList[i].id);
    }
    const matches = this.compareJson.filter(object =>
      this.checkedIDs.includes(object.id)
    );
    console.log(matches);
  }
  submit() {
    const matches = this.compareJson.filter(object =>
      this.checkedIDs.includes(object.id)
    );
    console.log(matches);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pre-populate `isChecked` for each item in `checkboxesDataList`? Also, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892383/how-to-pre-select-and-update-checkboxes-in-angular-2

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

I like another approach explained in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63797930/get-multiple-checkbox-value-as-an-array-in-angular/63799360#63799360)

```
<li *ngFor="let item of checkboxesDataList">
    <input #check type="checkbox" [ngModel]="checkedIDs && checkedIDs.indexOf(item.id)"
        (ngModelChange)="change(item.id,check.checked">{{item.label}}
</li>
```

The function change:

```
change(id:any,checked:boolean)
  {
     if (checked && this.checkedIDs.indexOf(option)<0)
         this.checkedIDs=[...this.checkedIDs,id]
         .sort((a,b)=>this.checkboxesDataList.findIndex(x=>x.id==a)>
                            this.checkboxesDataList.findIndex(x=>x.id==b)?1:-1)
    if (!checked)
    {
          this.checkedIDs=this.checkedIDs.filter(x=>x!=id)
          if (!this.checkedIDs.length)
             this.checkedIDs=null
    }
  }
```

So you only need use

```
  this.CheckedIDs=['c002','c003']
```

Comment: There is totally change of code, I need to make it in my existing code with few modifications